# In Cocoa/Interface Builder, how to clear text in textfield after button click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, button, interface-builder

I am making a simple Twitter update application using [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)

And I can't seem to get the TextField in Interface Builder to clear the text after they click the "update" button.  Is there an easy method that I could do this with or something in Interface Builder?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;

[textField setStringValue:@""];
[textField display];
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you also need to define a IBAction method like:

```
- (IBAction) clearText:(id) sender {
    [textField setStringValue:@""];
    [textField display];
}
```

You can now assign a button event (e.g. button down) to this action.

Comment: I assumed that he already has an action since he has an "Update" button. That's why I only added the outlet.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that it probably isn't when the button is pressed that the NSTextField is cleared, but when the tweet is uploaded.

Else you risk losing the tweet if it couldn't be sent for some reason.

[Not a solution to the direct question, but a solution to follow-up problem...]

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the question, as opposed to an answer.